# Find all combinations of tokens that form a given string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, recursion

I need to find all possible combinations of keys of a given map, including duplicates, that form a particular string. The problem looks quite simple, but I don't even know where to start.

---

I have already tried brute-forcing all existing combinations, which fell short when the input string didn't contain all the existing keys, not to mention it also was terribly inefficient.

My next guess was using recursive functions. Unfortunately, I'm far from the best when it comes to using them; after a couple of hours of blind fiddling and Googling in parallel, I finally had enough and resorted to asking a question here.

Here's my code, stripped of the little logic I had:

```
var map = {
    "01":  "A",
    "100": "B",
    "101": "C",
    "10":  "D",
    "111": "E",
    "000": "F"
}

function waysToDecode(input, keys, values) {
    ...
    return arrayOfPossibleDecodings;
}
```

**Input:**

```
>> waysToDecode("1010110", Object.keys(map), Object.values(map));
```

**Output:**

```
["DCD", "CAD"]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Also, I'm wondering if this or a similar algorithm has a name; the problem looks general enough to be given one.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```js
const map = {
  "01":  "A",
  "100": "B",
  "101": "C",
  "10":  "D",
  "111": "E",
  "000": "F"
};

// recursive function. Splits the string into 2 possible ways at each level
// a two possibility / a three. call the function itself with remaning part of the string
const buildTree = (input) => {
 if (!input) {
   return [];
  }
 // if input length is less than 2 return
  // we came down the wrong path
 if (input.length < 2) { 
   return;
  }
  
 if (input.length == 2 || input.length == 3 ) {
   // if its a valid entry we will have the mapped value for the key, if not its a invlaid path
    if (map[input]) {
      return [map[input]];
    } else {
     return;
    }
  }

 // if we have length more than 3 then we try to break it into 2 paths
  // 1. with length 2
  // 2. with length 3
  let valueTwo = map[input.slice(0, 2)];
  let valueThree = map[input.slice(0, 3)];
  let possibleCombinations = [];
  if (valueTwo) {
   let subCombinations = buildTree(input.slice(2));
    if (subCombinations) {
     possibleCombinations = [...subCombinations.map(value => `${valueTwo}${value}`)];
    }
  }
  if (valueThree) {
   let subCombinations = buildTree(input.slice(3));
    if (subCombinations) {
     possibleCombinations = [...possibleCombinations, ...subCombinations.map(value => `${valueThree}${value}`)];
    }
  }
  
  return possibleCombinations;
};

function waysToDecode(input) {
    let arrayOfPossibleDecodings = buildTree(input);
    return arrayOfPossibleDecodings || [];
}

document.write(waysToDecode("1010110"));
```